# Inject 3rd party final class

Tags: java, spring, amazon-s3, dependency-injection

I am trying to set up a service that pulls encrypted values from AWS KMS (amazon's Key management service) given the bucket, key and region.

Doing this is not the issue I am having but when I go to unit test I don't really want to test a 3rd party method or integration test and call it a unit test.

I want to be able to mock that class to just return back garbage text for testing.

Where I am struggling is with the AmazonS3ClientBuilder.

How can i create a bean to return an instance of this without doing something like this.

```
@Configuration
Public class config {
    @Bean
    public AmazonS3ClientBuilder amazonS3ClientBuilder{
        return AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard();
    }
}
```

Here is how I am currently using this.

```
AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withCredentials(new AWSSTaticCredentialsProvider(credentaials)).withRegion(region).build();
```

Am I looking at this wrong and should be injecting an AmazonS3 for the client instead of the builder?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you should inject the actual S3Client instead, and leave its construction and config in your Configuration class. Then when your tests run, you can just configure another S3Client Bean that returns a mock, using something like Mockito.

Comment: If the inputs needed for the creation of the client aren't known till runtime how would i accommodate that as I won't be able to create the client without it.

Comment: How would you accommodate that in general, or specifically for your test cases?

Comment: touche... I guess I need a mechanism to take the region, credentials and return a client. And I do not see methods to do that after the fact on the 3rd party class.

Comment: That's what I'm thinking as well. Whether you inject a builder or not, you will still need to define all those things at runtime (region, creds, etc), the only difference is if you do it in bean config, or somewhere else that utilizes the builder. That's also what it makes more sense to me to just inject the client itself, because your consumers of that client ideally shouldn't need to do additional config, they should just receive a pre-built client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To put what we had discussed into an example, how about something like this:

**Application configuration**

```
@Configuration
public class Config {
    @Bean
    public AmazonS3 getClient(){
        //TODO: Pull whatever you need from KMS, create credentials, define region, etc
        return AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withRegion("my region").build();
    }

}
```

This is what normally gets injected into the application. Instead of injecting the builder, I'm instead injecting a pre-constructed S3Client. Then, in my unit tests I can do:

**Sample unit test**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(loader=AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
public class SampleTest {

    @Configuration
    static class ContextConfiguration {
        @Bean
        public AmazonS3 gets3(){
            System.out.println("Providing mocked s3...");
            //TODO: Provide when/then statements, etc
            return Mockito.mock(AmazonS3.class);
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testSomething(){
      //TODO: Test something that utilizes S3Client
    }
}
```

Which should instead provide a Mocked version of the S3Client when the test is run. This is a bit of a bare bones example, another option would be to take a similar approach but use `@Profile` to active a test profile. Or you could even hide all the s3 interaction behind another class, and mock that instead as a means of abstracting the s3 implementation away from classes that need to deal with storage.